# can't initialise audiotrack to record or play

Tags: android, audio-recording, audiotrack

I've been trying to figure this out for days and have been through tons of threads on here with no luck. I'm trying to record to a file when a button on the grid is clicked, save it, and then play it.

When the program is starting up I get this:

```
09-11 18:00:15.357    1076-1076/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/AudioRecord﹕ Could not get audio input for record source 1
09-11 18:00:15.357    1076-1076/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/AudioRecord-JNI﹕ Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
09-11 18:00:15.357    1076-1076/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/android.media.AudioRecord﹕ Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
09-11 18:00:15.367    1076-1076/com.spookyapps.lollatone D/d﹕ Attempting rate 8000Hz, bits: 3, channel: 16
09-11 18:00:15.367    1076-1076/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/android.media.AudioRecord﹕ getMinBufferSize(): Invalid audio format.
09-11 18:00:15.367    1076-1076/com.spookyapps.lollatone D/d﹕ Attempting rate 8000Hz, bits: 3, channel: 12
09-11 18:00:15.367    1076-1076/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/android.media.AudioRecord﹕ getMinBufferSize(): Invalid audio format.
09-11 18:00:15.367    1076-1076/com.spookyapps.lollatone D/d﹕ Attempting rate 8000Hz, bits: 2, channel: 16
09-11 18:00:15.567    1076-1076/com.spookyapps.lollatone D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb743ab50, tid 1076
09-11 18:00:15.647    1076-1076/com.spookyapps.lollatone W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

When I try clicking a button to start everything I get this:

```
09-11 18:03:59.287    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/android.media.AudioRecord﹕ getMinBufferSize(): Invalid audio format.
09-11 18:03:59.287    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone D/Sounds﹕ Attempting rate 8000Hz, bits: 2, channel: 16
09-11 18:03:59.287    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/AudioRecord﹕ Could not get audio input for record source 1
09-11 18:03:59.287    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/AudioRecord-JNI﹕ Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
09-11 18:03:59.287    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/android.media.AudioRecord﹕ Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
09-11 18:03:59.297    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone D/Sounds﹕ Attempting rate 8000Hz, bits: 2, channel: 12
09-11 18:03:59.297    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/AudioRecord﹕ Could not get audio input for record source 1
09-11 18:03:59.297    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/AudioRecord-JNI﹕ Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
09-11 18:03:59.297    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/android.media.AudioRecord﹕ Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
09-11 18:03:59.297    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone D/Sounds﹕ Attempting rate 11025Hz, bits: 3, channel: 16
09-11 18:03:59.297    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/android.media.AudioRecord﹕ getMinBufferSize(): Invalid audio format.
09-11 18:03:59.297    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone D/Sounds﹕ Attempting rate 11025Hz, bits: 3, channel: 12
09-11 18:03:59.297    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/android.media.AudioRecord﹕ getMinBufferSize(): Invalid audio format.
09-11 18:03:59.297    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone D/Sounds﹕ Attempting rate 11025Hz, bits: 2, channel: 16
09-11 18:03:59.297    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/AudioRecord﹕ Could not get audio input for record source 1
09-11 18:03:59.297    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/AudioRecord-JNI﹕ Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
09-11 18:03:59.297    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/android.media.AudioRecord﹕ Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
09-11 18:03:59.297    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone D/Sounds﹕ Attempting rate 11025Hz, bits: 2, channel: 12
09-11 18:03:59.297    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/AudioRecord﹕ Could not get audio input for record source 1
09-11 18:03:59.297    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/AudioRecord-JNI﹕ Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
09-11 18:03:59.297    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/android.media.AudioRecord﹕ Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
09-11 18:03:59.317    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone D/Sounds﹕ Attempting rate 22050Hz, bits: 3, channel: 16
09-11 18:03:59.317    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/android.media.AudioRecord﹕ getMinBufferSize(): Invalid audio format.
09-11 18:03:59.317    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone D/Sounds﹕ Attempting rate 22050Hz, bits: 3, channel: 12
09-11 18:03:59.317    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/android.media.AudioRecord﹕ getMinBufferSize(): Invalid audio format.
09-11 18:03:59.317    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone D/Sounds﹕ Attempting rate 22050Hz, bits: 2, channel: 16
09-11 18:03:59.317    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/AudioRecord﹕ Could not get audio input for record source 1
09-11 18:03:59.317    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/AudioRecord-JNI﹕ Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
09-11 18:03:59.317    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/android.media.AudioRecord﹕ Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
09-11 18:03:59.317    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone D/Sounds﹕ Attempting rate 22050Hz, bits: 2, channel: 12
09-11 18:03:59.317    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/AudioRecord﹕ Could not get audio input for record source 1
09-11 18:03:59.317    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/AudioRecord-JNI﹕ Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
09-11 18:03:59.317    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/android.media.AudioRecord﹕ Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
09-11 18:03:59.317    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone D/Sounds﹕ Attempting rate 44100Hz, bits: 3, channel: 16
09-11 18:03:59.317    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/android.media.AudioRecord﹕ getMinBufferSize(): Invalid audio format.
09-11 18:03:59.317    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone D/Sounds﹕ Attempting rate 44100Hz, bits: 3, channel: 12
09-11 18:03:59.317    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/android.media.AudioRecord﹕ getMinBufferSize(): Invalid audio format.
09-11 18:03:59.317    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone D/Sounds﹕ Attempting rate 44100Hz, bits: 2, channel: 16
09-11 18:03:59.317    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/AudioRecord﹕ Could not get audio input for record source 1
09-11 18:03:59.317    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/AudioRecord-JNI﹕ Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
09-11 18:03:59.317    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/android.media.AudioRecord﹕ Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
09-11 18:03:59.317    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone D/Sounds﹕ Attempting rate 44100Hz, bits: 2, channel: 12
09-11 18:03:59.337    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/AudioRecord﹕ Could not get audio input for record source 1
09-11 18:03:59.337    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/AudioRecord-JNI﹕ Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
09-11 18:03:59.337    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/android.media.AudioRecord﹕ Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
09-11 18:03:59.347    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/AudioRecord﹕ Could not get audio input for record source 1
09-11 18:03:59.347    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/AudioRecord-JNI﹕ Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
09-11 18:03:59.347    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/android.media.AudioRecord﹕ Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
09-11 18:03:59.357    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/AudioRecord﹕ Recording Failed
09-11 18:03:59.367    1141-1141/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/AudioTrack﹕ Playback Failed
```

here is my main activity:

```
package com.spookyapps.lollatone;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Sounds mSound = new Sounds();

        GridView gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                mSound.findAudioRecord();
                mSound.record();

                mSound.play();


            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and my sound class: I've been trying to fix it by hacking in other "Fixes" I've found on here but nothing is working. It tries now at first to find the proper sample rate and stuff but that still does not solve the issue.

```
package com.spookyapps.lollatone;

import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

/**
 * Created by abc on 9/7/2014.
 */
public class Sounds {

    private static final String TAG = Sounds.class.getSimpleName();
    public boolean mIsRecording = false;
    int frequency = 11025;
    private static int[] mSampleRates = new int[] { 8000, 11025, 22050, 44100 };
    int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
    int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
    int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(frequency, channelConfiguration, audioEncoding);

    String mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

    File file = new File(mFileName);


    InputStream is;
    BufferedInputStream bis;
    DataInputStream dis;
    AudioRecord record = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            frequency, channelConfiguration,
            audioEncoding, bufferSize);

    OutputStream os;
    BufferedOutputStream bos;
    DataOutputStream dos;

    public AudioRecord findAudioRecord() {
        for (int rate : mSampleRates) {
            for (short audioFormat : new short[] { AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT }) {
                for (short channelConfig : new short[] { AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO }) {
                    try {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Attempting rate " + rate + "Hz, bits: " + audioFormat + ", channel: "
                                + channelConfig);
                        int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(rate, channelConfig, audioFormat);

                        if (bufferSize != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
                            // check if we can instantiate and have a success
                            AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT, rate, channelConfig, audioFormat, bufferSize);

                            if (recorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED)
                                return recorder;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, rate + "Exception, keep trying.",e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    AudioRecord recorder = findAudioRecord();


    public void record() {

        String mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        mFileName += "/audioTest/" + "reverseme.pcm";
        File file = new File(mFileName);



        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        } else {

            //create the new file

            file.mkdirs();

        }
        try {
            // Create a DataOutputStream to write the audio data into the saved file
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

            // Create a new AudioRecord object to record the audio
            bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(frequency, channelConfiguration, audioEncoding);
            recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                    frequency, channelConfiguration,
                    audioEncoding, bufferSize);

            short[] buffer = new short[bufferSize];
            recorder.startRecording();
            mIsRecording = true;

            new Timer().schedule(stop(), 5000);  //time in miliseconds

            while (mIsRecording) {
                int bufferReadResult = recorder.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                for (int i = 0; i < bufferReadResult; i++) {
                    dos.writeShort(buffer[i]);
                }
            }

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e("AudioRecord", "Recording Failed");
        }

    }

    public void play() {
        // get the file to play back
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                + "/reverseme.pcm");
        //Get the length of the audio stored in the file (16 bit so 2 bytes per short)
        //and create a short array to store the recorded audio
        int musicLength = (int) (file.length());
        short[] music = new short[musicLength];

        try {
            //Create a DataInputStream to read the audio data back from the saved file


            //Read the file into the music array
            int i = 0;
            while (dis.available() > 0) {
                music[musicLength - 1 - i] = dis.readShort();
                i++;
            }

            // close the input streams
            dis.close();


            // Create a new AudioTrack object using the same parameters as the AudioRecord
            // object used to create the file

            AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    11025,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                    musicLength,
                    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
            // Start playback
            audioTrack.play();

            //Write the music buffer to the AudioTrack object
            audioTrack.write(music, 0, musicLength);

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e("AudioTrack", "Playback Failed");
        }
    }

    public TimerTask stop() {
        TimerTask t = new TimerTask() {


            @Override
            public void run() {
                mIsRecording = false;
                record.stop();
                record.release();
                try {
                    dos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        return t;

    }
}
```